# Python read from file - newline

Tags: python, list, parsing, newline

I am writing a list (simple[]) to a file using writelines() and I need each item from the list to be on a new line in the file. I am using the following code:

```
file_path_simple = r'[path_redacted]\tx_list_simple.txt'
    with open(file_path_simple, 'w') as fp:
        for i in simple:
            #ignores any blank lines
            if i == '':
                continue
            else:
                fp.writelines([i])
                fp.writelines('\n')
        fp.close()
```

The problem I am having is that when read from the file later it includes the \n, so instead of python reading:

`blablabla`

it reads:

`blablabla\n`

How can I make it not read the \n? Or do I need to use something like re.split() to remove the \n prior to reading?

This seems like something really simple I am overlooking.

Comment: `blablabla\n` That is a perfectly normal result from reading a line in a file.  In most situations you would just call `.strip()` to remove the newline after reading if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rstrip`.

```py
i = i.rstrip('\n')
```